Hamiltonians on compact surface
Let $\Sigma$ be a compact, connected surface with a non-empty boundary, equipped with an area form $\omega$. Consider a time-dependent, 1-periodic Hamiltonian $H \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z} \times \Sigma)$ such that for each $t$, $H_t$ is constant on each boundary component. Is it true that the Hamiltonian vector field $X_{H}$ is tangent to the boundary, and $\partial{\Sigma}$ is preserved under the flow of $X_H$?

It is an elementary fact of linear algebra that if $\omega=dx\wedge dy$ and $\alpha$ is a linear functional on $\mathbb R^2$ vanishing on the $x$-axis, then there exists a vector ${\bf u}=(a,0)\in \mathbb R^2$ such that
$$
\omega({\bf u}, {\bf v})=\alpha({\bf v})\  \ \ \forall {\bf v}\in \mathbb R^2.  
$$
Applying this for every fixed $t$ to the 1-form $dH(t,\cdot)$, it follows that your vector field $X_H$ is tangent to $\partial \Sigma$. Thus, the Hamiltonian flow of $H$ preserves $\partial \Sigma$.
